# Fiqah Ijama and Qiyass Problems

Tags: non-muslim, fiqh

Does Islam divide humanity into Darul Islam and darul harab? and Muslims must wage jihad against those who are unbelievers. while Islam is a religion of peace then why are such things in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

aww,

in the past, all countries, whether muslim or non muslim, saw anyone who didnt follow their religion as a threat, and therefore, there were lots of wars between countries of different faiths.

Since then, many countries have amicable relations with one another, and therefore do not fight each other.

Thus, Muslim countries could be called Darul Islam, non-muslim countries at war with islam are considered darul harb. The Darul Harb will differ from one country to another. Palestinians are at war with Israel, so they will consider Israel as a Darul harb. However, Jordon and Egypt are not, so to them, Israel is not Darul Harb. Neither is it a darul Islam. It is a third category, called darul Amn (Land of security). This is a land in which Muslims can fast, pray etc without too much difficulty. In Darul Harb countries, fasting, praying to Allah, and being Muslim would mean death. Since this does not happen in almost all countries of the world, it therefore follows that most countries of the world are Darul Amn (places of security) and not Darul Harb, so you have no need to fight them.

wwb